# How to replace a text inside of DOM node keeping its content as HTML

Tags: php, dom

I have a table, parse its cells with `DOMDocument` and need to replace some text inside of a cell keeping its content as HTML

This is simple example:

```
<?php
$html = '<table><tr><td>First <a href="#!">cell</a></td><td>Second cell</td></tr></table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {
    if(strpos($td->nodeValue,'First') !== false) {
        $thisTdHTML = $dom->saveXML($td);
        $td->nodeValue = '';
        $thisTdHTML = str_replace('First','First table',$thisTdHTML);
        $textNode = $dom->createTextNode($thisTdHTML);
        $td->appendChild($textNode);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML($dom);
?>
```

With the code HTML tags of the first cell including outer tags of the cell are displayed on browser

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Because it's a node you should work with it's children, not with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, according to *@u_mulder* comment, I've found this solution

```
<?php
$html = '<table><tr><td>First <a href="#!">cell</a></td><td>Second cell</td></tr></table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {
    if(strpos($td->nodeValue,'First') !== false) {
        foreach($td->childNodes as $child) {
            if(strpos($child->nodeValue,'First') !== false) {
                $child->nodeValue = str_replace('First','First table',$child->nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $dom->saveXML($dom);
?>
```

However, a child may contain another child(s). For example there may be a paragraph inside of a cell and it may contain a link and so on.

Is there a solution including any levels of nesting?